# Downloading files from ftp via UDP but path is not rendered

Tags: udp, tftp

**Preface**: This has to be done only via UDP. No TCP!

**Enviroment**: Client:Kali Linux OS.  Server:Windows 10

*Connection is established since other files were downloaded.
Tab to auto-fill is not available because it is udp connection*

**Question**. Downloading files from ftp via UDP but path is not rendered as intended.
I'm already running mssql server 2017 and file location is correct as I confirmed it.
I also checked Official website. [MicroSoft SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/file-locations-for-default-and-named-instances-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Path is `\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\master.bak`

The following is the command I tried.

```sh
tftp> get \Program\ Files\\Microsoft\ SQL\ Server\\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\Backup\\master.bak
#Added two backslash to indicate directory.
```

This returns an error

```sh
Error code 256: File '\Program\' does not exist
Error code 256: File 'Files\\Microsoft\' does not exist
Error code 256: File 'SQL\' does not exist
Error code 256: File 'Server\\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\Backup\\master.bak' does not exist
```

I did downloaded with

```sh
tftp> get \Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

How do you type correct path in this case?

**edit**:Someone told me about 8.3 filename convention.
Accessing from non-8.3 OS to 8.3 FIlesystem might cause a problem.
Still, I didn't get why backslash weren't really rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to find the way with tftp, but you can use tftpy:

```
pip install tftpy

python

Python 2.7.18 (default, Apr 20 2020, 20:30:41) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tftpy
>>> client = tftpy.TftpClient('192.168.1.20', 69)
>>> client.download('\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\master.bak', 'master.bak')
```